# How to change ngx-quill editor's placeholder font style?

Tags: css, angular, ngx-quill

I have the following web element in my angular project:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description<span>*</span></label>
    <div class="quill-container" [attr.data-hover]="hoverText">
        <quill-editor
        [(ngModel)]="tutorialDescription"
        class="example-form-field"
        (onContentChanged)="textChanged($event)"
        [formControl]="registerForm.get('desc')"
        appearance="outline"
        [placeholder]="message"
        type="text"
        id="description"
        name="description">
        </quill-editor>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the font style of the placeholder's text to be normal? I tried the inline

```
<quill-editor style="font-style: normal;" ...></quill-editor>
```

but it is not working.